# KeyError: 'rows' while trying to fetch view contents in couchdb

Tags: python, couchdb

I am starting to make a couchdb database, but unfortunately I've found an error that keeps me stalled.

I have in the database some documents like this:

```
{
  "_id": "001169c8-16a9-400b-831d-61f4134e1cd3",
  "_rev": "2-c95e7385f0ad6a249906a8a2e60341de",
  "type": "word",
  "word": "quién",
  "creation-date": "2020-12-19T19:54:06.954539",
  "sentences": {
    "00789ff2-e38e-414b-a3f5-c2282aeeb42e": {
      "sentence": "No sé       quién se lo ha metido por la cabeza, dice que le pongo en ridículo       si no voy",
      "source": "foundation",
      "date": "2020-12-19T19:47:48.114888"
    },
    "01b40374-1103-4fd5-95dd-fd5d8eddbd21": {
      "sentence": "— Y a vuestra merced, ¿quién le fía, señor cura",
      "source": "foundation",
      "date": "2020-12-19T19:43:10.510990"
    }
  }
}
```

And I've designed a view to recover only the "word" part of these documents:

```
function (doc) {
  if( doc.type == 'word')
  emit(doc.word, 1);
}
```

Finnally, in python, I've created a simple script to recover the docs in that view:

```
def processEntries( db : couchdb.Database ):
    for row in db.iterview( '_design/all_words', 100, group=True ) :
        print( f"{row=}")
```

But unfortunately, I am getting this error (only last lines are shown):

```
  File "/home/rluna/wkcpp/lib/corpus_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/couchdb/client.py", line 1041, in iterview
    rows = list(self.view(name, wrapper, **options))
  File "/home/rluna/wkcpp/lib/corpus_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/couchdb/client.py", line 1361, in __len__
    return len(self.rows)
  File "/home/rluna/wkcpp/lib/corpus_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/couchdb/client.py", line 1378, in rows
    self._fetch()
  File "/home/rluna/wkcpp/lib/corpus_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/couchdb/client.py", line 1366, in _fetch
    self._rows = [wrapper(row) for row in data['rows']]
KeyError: 'rows'
```

Any ideas of what's going on?

Comment: Are you are using `reduce: "_sum"`? In general, I would determine the query URL and look at it directly with curl or a browser to see why there are no rows since coucdb often doesn't return rows in cases like error results, etc.

Comment: @lossleader, I've tried to do a curl command: curl -X GET $couch/$db/_design/all_words/_view/all_words and retrieves all the data

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. First of all, the `group=True` is incorrect for this context, because I don't want to group the results at all.

Secondly, the problem was in the way the view has to be called. The view is inside a design document, so to uniquely identify the view, you have to provide the name of the design document **and** the view document. In other words, the python code has to be changed this way:

```
def processEntries( db : couchdb.Database ):
    for row in db.iterview( 'all_words/all_words', 100 ) :
        print( f"{row=}")
```